# 2-step 3D rotation of x,y,z tensors

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, rotation, pytorch

### In Python, using [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html), I'm trying to rotate 3 cubes `x`, `y`, and `z`, first about the x-axis and then about the z-axis. However, the rotation about the z-axis seems to be behaving in a way I would not expect.

I am creating 3 cubes to rotate below and then rotating them 90 degrees about the x-axis and then 90 degrees about the z-axis.

```
import torch 
from numpy import pi 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rotation(x,y,z,theta,phi):
    ### A function for rotating about the x and then z axes ###
    xx = (x*torch.cos(theta)) - (((y*torch.cos(phi)) - (z*torch.sin(phi)))*torch.sin(theta))
    yy = (x*torch.sin(theta)) + (((y*torch.cos(phi)) - (z*torch.sin(phi)))*torch.cos(theta))
    zz = (y*torch.sin(phi)) + (z*torch.cos(phi))
    return xx,yy,zz

### Creating the 3 cubes: x, y, z ###
l = torch.arange(-2,3,1)
x,y,z=torch.meshgrid(l,l,l)

###  Scaling the cubes so they can be differentiated from one another ###
x = x.clone().T
y = y.clone().T*2
z = z.clone().T*3

### Defining the amount of rotation about the x and z axes
phi = torch.tensor([pi/2]).to(torch.float) # about the x axis
theta = torch.tensor([pi/2]).to(torch.float) # about the z axis

### Performing the rotation
x_r,y_r,z_r = rotation(x, y, z, theta, phi)
```

By visualising the first slice of each cube I can see that the rotation has not been successful as at first glance it looks like the cubes have actually been rotated about the x-axis followed by the y-axis instead.

[image]

Is there a specific way that Python handles rotations like this that I'm missing, such as the axes changing along with rotations, meaning the initial [rotation matrix operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) no longer applies?

---

#### Extra information

If one were to replace `theta` as `0` instead of `pi/2`, it can be seen that the first rotation behaves as expected by looking at the first slice of each rotated cube:

Code for visualising:

```
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(231)
x_before = plt.imshow(x[0,:,:])
plt.xlabel('x-before'); plt.colorbar(x_before,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
plt.subplot(232)
y_before = plt.imshow(y[0,:,:])
plt.xlabel('y-before'); plt.colorbar(y_before,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
plt.subplot(233)
z_before = plt.imshow(z[0,:,:])
plt.xlabel('z-before'); plt.colorbar(z_before,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
plt.subplot(234)
x_after = plt.imshow(x_r[0,:,:])
plt.xlabel('x-after'); plt.colorbar(x_after,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
plt.subplot(235)
y_after = plt.imshow(y_r[0,:,:])
plt.xlabel('y-after'); plt.colorbar(y_after,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
plt.subplot(236)
z_after = plt.imshow(z_r[0,:,:])
plt.xlabel('z-after'); plt.colorbar(z_after,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a global vs local axis problem - you are rotating 90 degrees around the X axis to start with, which moves your cube so that its local Y axis ends up pointing along the global Z axis. Applying the next rotation of 90 degrees around global Z looks like a rotation around the local Y axis.

To solve this you either need to apply different rotations to achieve the orientation you want (in this case rotate -90 degrees around global Y, since the local Z axis is now facing down the negative global Y axis), or write a different rotation function that can rotate around any vector and track the local axes of the cube (by passing them through the same rotations as the cube itself).

You may also be able to work in local coordinates, by applying the rotations in reverse order, ie a global rotation around Y by 90, followed by a global rotation around X by 90 will be equivalent to local rotations in X then Y.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem here is that once the local Y axis is pointing along the global Z axis, I apply a rotation around the global Z axis which for some reason looks like a rotation around the global Y axis here instead. Achieving a rotation about the now local Y axis is actually what I want here but as I'm using matrix formulations I thought this should work as I'm trying to rotate globally at all times

Comment: That's just it - your rotation function takes something as input, and rotates it along a global axis. That's the only operation you can perform, so you need to track the axes yourself and, in the knowledge that local Y and Z have moved, rotate with a different global axis. It's difficult to see since you are always using 90 degrees, which has the effect of swapping your axes around. What happens if your initial X rotation were 45 degrees? Now the local Y axis points diagonally and a single rotation around a global axis can't perform a diagonal rotation like that.

Comment: Ah okay yeah that's what I mean though (sorry I'm not being very clear). I want to rotate the cubes globally and globally only, about the global X and then the global Z, regardless of where the local axes change to (they will change predictably given known theta and phi). I don't want to rotate by the object's (or the cubes') local axes, I simply want to rotate by global X and global Z. But the images above are showing that rather than rotating by global Z for the second rotation, they're rotating by global Y...which is very strange as like you say I'm only rotating by global axes.

Comment: Maybe I'm also misunderstanding. The fact that the z works when x is 0 still makes it feel like it's a local to global, maybe not in the rotations themselves but something hidden in the details of calculating xx,yy and zz?

Comment: I've had a long think about this and I think I now realise the problem. This kind of rotation tells the user what the xyz values would be if rotating by angles around some axes (which go through the origin), but keeps the axes fixed. Here my question is effectively "what are the point values given that I rotate the axes themselves". So I think the real answer here is to use spherical coordinate transformations not rotation matrices.

Comment: The last part of my answer above may let you do this with the code you already have - applying the rotations in reverse order will have the same effect as 'rotating the axes themselves'.

Comment: Tried the rotations in reverse order and you are right this did work! Although I've now realised that it's not actually rotating the cubes themselves but evaluating a rotation of many points within an xyz framework whereas what I originally intended to do was physically rotate each individual cube. But that's a different question to this thread I think so I'll not post about it here :)